# HttpClient client-side message handlers

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-web-api

The `HttpClient` custom Client Message Handlers insert themselves in the **client-side** pipeline when making web api calls. This info is from [this article](http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/web-api-clients/httpclient-message-handlers)
The author says that these message handlers go into action as the request is being sent out and also when the response is received back from the server.

I understand these client message handler's role as request is being sent out from client to the Server because the `sendAsync` method provides the request object. One can add custom request headers, etc.

I do not understand the usefulness of these message handlers AFTER the response is received from the server because the `sendAsync` method **does not provide access to the response object**. So, I am not sure how these client side message handlers are useful on the return journey of the request.

I am obviously missing something here.

Answer (score 0):

Actually you do get access to the response message inside the message handler. For example, in the following handler, I am logging outgoing request and incoming response. Now as long as I use this instance of HttpClient, all calls made through it write traces of requests and response.

```
HttpClient client = new HttpClient(new LoggingHandler(new HttpClientHandler()));

public class LoggingHandler : DelegatingHandler
{
    public LoggingHandler(HttpMessageHandler innerHandler)
        : base(innerHandler)
    {
    }

    protected override async Task<HttpResponseMessage> SendAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Request:");
        Console.WriteLine(request.ToString());
        if (request.Content != null)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(await request.Content.ReadAsStringAsync());
        }
        Console.WriteLine();

        HttpResponseMessage response = await base.SendAsync(request, cancellationToken);

        Console.WriteLine("Response:");
        Console.WriteLine(response.ToString());
        if (response.Content != null)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync());
        }
        Console.WriteLine();

        return response;
    }
}
```